# R: How can I transfer values from multiple data frames to another data frame depending on certain conditions?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

Is there a way in R to transfer values from multiple data frames to a second data frame if certain conditions are met? Specifically, I am concerned with the following problem:

I have values for different people in data frame 1 (columns: name, country in ISO-3, year1, year2), polity scores for all countries in data frame 2 (columns: country in ISO-3, year, score) and gdp for all countries in data frame 3 (columns: country in ISO-3, year, gdp)

I would now like to add the corresponding polity scores from data frame 2 and gdp value from data frame 3 to data frame 1 as a new columns depending on country and year for year1 and year 2. Can I automate this via R?

**df1**

| name | country | year1 | year2 | polity_year1 | gdp_year1 | polity_year2 | gdp_year2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | USA | 1990 | 2018 | *polity score: year1* | *gdp: year1* | *polity score: year2* | gdp: year2 |
| Name 2 | DNK | 1995 | 1999 | *polity score: year1* | *gdp: year1* | *polity score: year2* | gdp: year2 |

**df2**

| country | year | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1990 | 10 |
| USA | 2018 | 10 |
| DNK | 1995 | 10 |
| DNK | 1999 | 10 |

**df3**

| country | year | gdp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1990 | 5325 |
| USA | 2018 | 7230 |
| DNK | 1995 | 2245 |
| DNK | 1999 | 3256 |

I tried dplyr join(),

```
df_joined <-  left_join(df1, df2, by = c("country" = "country", "year_1" = "year"), name="polity_year1") %>%

     left_join(df1, df2, by = c("country" = "country", "year_2" = "year"),name="polity_year2") %>%

     left_join(df1, df3, by = c("country" = "country", "year_1" = "year"), name="gdp_year1") %>%

     left_join(df1, df3, by = c("country" = "country", "year_2" = "year"), name="gdp_year2")
```

but that fails for several reasons

- I can only run the function for one year of df1
- I can't run the function using %>% for df2 (polity) and df3 (gdp) at the same time
- I can't set the new column names in df1 depending on year in df1 (e.g. "polity_year1" or "gdp_year2")

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to first do a pivot_longer() so that the years are in a separate row, then when you run the joins, they might work.

Comment: Also, in your code, the first value after the pipe comes from the previous line, i.e. after the `%>%` the `d1` in `left_join(df1, df2, ...` should be removed, otherwise **R** will see three values for a join, when only two are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue id that your `df1` dataset isn't in a tidy data format, which means each row is one observation, each column is one variable. In contrast, in your df1 the variables year, gdp and polity_score are spread over two columns. Hence, to solve your task it's best to reshape your data first before joining. To this end I make use of `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1_tidy <- df1 %>% 
  rename(year_year1 = year1, year_year2 = year2) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("year"), as.character)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(name, country), names_to = c("var", "year1"), names_pattern = "^(.*)_(.*)$") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-year1) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(year))

df1_tidy
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   name   country  year polity              gdp       
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr>               <chr>     
#> 1 Name 1 USA      1990 polity score: year1 gdp: year1
#> 2 Name 1 USA      2018 polity score: year2 gdp: year2
#> 3 Name 2 DNK      1995 polity score: year1 gdp: year1
#> 4 Name 2 DNK      1999 polity score: year2 gdp: year2
df1_tidy %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("country", "year"), suffix = c("", "_country")) %>% 
  left_join(df3, by = c("country", "year"), suffix = c("", "_country"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>   name   country  year polity              gdp        score gdp_country
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr>               <chr>      <int>       <int>
#> 1 Name 1 USA      1990 polity score: year1 gdp: year1    10        5325
#> 2 Name 1 USA      2018 polity score: year2 gdp: year2    10        7230
#> 3 Name 2 DNK      1995 polity score: year1 gdp: year1    10        2245
#> 4 Name 2 DNK      1999 polity score: year2 gdp: year2    10        3256
```